# How to copy properties from one list to another using Linq conditionally

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of custom objects.
Both have `DivisionId` as common propery. I want to copy two parameters, `PlanType` and `CoverageType`, from `List<Divisions>` to `List<Members>` using Linq, whenever `Member.DivisionId = Divisions.DivisionId`.

The Member and Divisions objects are given below :

```
public class Members
{
  public string FirstName;
  public string LastName;
  public string DivisionId;
}

Public Class Divisions
{
  public string PlanType;
  public string CoverageType,
  public string DivisionId;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Members class does not contains PlanType and CoverageType, how can you copy those values in there ?

Comment: Copy `PlanType` and `CoverageType` into what?

Comment: Do the items at each index match, do you need to search for an item in another list when you have it in the first List?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is **Join**

```
    var query = from m in members
                join d in divisions on m.DivisionId equals d.DivisionId
                select new { m.FirstName,
                            m.LastName,
                            m.DivisionId,
                            d.CoverageType,
                            d.PlanType
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the item from index 0 in the first list to index 0 in the second, and so on for all of the other indexes you can do this:

```
var pairs = members.Zip(divisions, (a, b) => new
{
    Member = a,
    Division = b,
});

foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    Copy(pair.Member, pair.Division);
}
```

If the indexes don't match you need to do a join:

```
var pairs = members.Join(divisions
    , member => member.DivisionId
    , division => division.DivisionId
    , (a, b) => new
    {
        Member = a,
        Division = b,
    });

foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    Copy(pair.Member, pair.Division);
}
```

Note that the `Zip` will be faster, if the items are already in the proper order.  Join will be slower than the Zip, but will be faster than manually re-ordering the items to allow a `Zip`.